# How can I reset the content of Windows.Form in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PS script where first I create a Windows.Forms.Form object, then I add a paint to it so there is a circles and two lines visible, then I want to RESET the form so its all clear and draw another yellow circle, so that only the yellow circle is visible. However, I can't make the previous paint(green circle with two red lines) dissapear. Is there any way to reset the form content?

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Drawing")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Drawing.Color")

$myBrush = new-object Drawing.SolidBrush green
$myYellowBrush = New-Object Drawing.SolidBrush yellow
$mypen = new-object Drawing.Pen black


$rect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 10, 10, 180, 180
$sencondRect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 30, 30, 60, 60

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.SetBounds(300,300,800,600)

$formGraphics = $form.createGraphics()
$form.Refresh()
$form.Show() 
Write-Output "hello" 

$form.add_paint(
{

$formGraphics.FillEllipse($myBrush, $rect) 

$mypen.color = "red"
$mypen.width = 5    

$formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen, 10, 10, 190, 190)

$formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen, 190, 10, 10, 190) 

}
)
Start-Sleep -s 1

$form.ResetForeColor()

$form.ResetBackColor()


$formGraphics = $form.createGraphics()
$form.add_paint(
{
    $myYellowBrush = New-Object Drawing.SolidBrush yellow
    $sencondRect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 30, 30, 60, 60
$formGraphics.FillEllipse($myYellowBrush, $sencondRect) 
}
)
$form.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Paint is an handler to be "cycled". Try using an if statement:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Drawing")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Drawing.Color")

$myBrush = new-object Drawing.SolidBrush green
$myYellowBrush = New-Object Drawing.SolidBrush yellow
$mypen = new-object Drawing.Pen red
$mypen.Width = 5

$rect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 10, 10, 180, 180
$secondRect = new-object Drawing.Rectangle 30, 30, 60, 60

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.SetBounds(300,300,800,600)
$form.Show()

$formGraphics = $form.createGraphics()
$formGraphics2 = $form.createGraphics()
$crossMode = $true
$form.add_paint({
  if($crossMode) {
    $formGraphics.FillEllipse($myBrush, $rect) 
    $formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen, 10, 10, 190, 190)
    $formGraphics.DrawLine($mypen, 190, 10, 10, 190) 
  } else {
    $formGraphics2.FillEllipse($myYellowBrush, $secondRect) 
  }
})
$form.Refresh()

Start-Sleep -s 1
$crossMode = $false
$form.Refresh()

Start-Sleep -s 5
$form.Close()
```